# Can you do .End in excel if there are blank columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that builds a table row by row.

Once it puts the data in each cell in the row, it selects the entire row using

`Range(Cells(2 + RowOffset, 2), Range(Cells(2 + RowOffset, 2), Cells(2 + RowOffset, 2)).End(xlToRight)).Interior.Color = vbBlack`

and makes it black.

This was working great, until one of the table cells didn't have any data. At that point the code only selects the row up until the cell after the empty cell.

Is there a method to do .End to select the entire row, regardless of if there are blank cells in the middle? Obviously I still want to only select rows with data in.

Just to clarify, if X is data and 0 is blank:

> X X X X X

> X X O X X

> X X X X O

The code would highlight the first row all 5 cells, highlight the second row all 5 cells, highlight the last row just 4 cells (because the O on the last row is no data)

Comment: Instead of using `End(xlToRight)`, use `End(xlToLeft)` starting from the *rightmost* cell.

Comment: I believe that suffers the same issue, because the documentation states it is the same as holding down `end` and pressing the `left arrow`, which when I try it causes the cursor to jump from the far right cell to the cell without any data in. Also, I don't know what the rightmost cell is because my table has dynamic columns.

Comment: Starting from the *rightmost cell on the sheet*. That would be `Cells(2 + RowOffset, Columns.Count)`.

Comment: Yes, if you open excel and type data X X O X X and then click the rightmost cell and press END+LEFT ARROW it will not jump to the start. Also Columns.Count is not a good way to get the number of columns in the table as there may be other data on the sheet elsewhere above or below it that extends out further.

Comment: `Columns.Count` is the count of columns in the *worksheet*

Comment: If you put every single word in this sentence into individual cells it would increase `Columns.Count` far past the end of the table below it, so when you highlighted table rows with 5 columns it would put a giant bar across the entire screen instead of just the 5 columns.

Comment: Please reread Tim's comment. `Columns.Count` is implicitly `ActiveSheet.Columns.Count`... the number of columns in the *entire worksheet*, not the number of columns in your table. The rightmost cell would be something like `XFD2`.

Comment: So as long as there's no content to the right of your table the suggested approach should work fine.

Comment: Sadly I can't guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

### From the First Cell to the Last Non-Empty Cell

- You have concluded yourself that the `End property` with its parameter set to `xlToRight` is not an option. Since you are fighting (in the comments) against an `xlToLeft` option, there is probably data to the right of the table or you just want to restrict the whole thing to only some (5) columns leaving the cells to the right intact. In any case, using the `Find method` is a better option.

**An Example**

- It is assumed that in **each row** you want to highlight the cells from column `B` to column `F` with the following condition:

  - If any of the cells are not empty, highlight the cells from the first cell to the last non-empty cell (no matter if there are empty cells in between).

```vb
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' change appropriately
    ' e.g.:
    'Dim ws As Worksheet: set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.Columns("B:F") ' "B1:F1048576"
    ' Or any of the following:
    'Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.Columns("B").Resize(, 5) ' "B1:F1048576"
    'Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.Columns(2).Resize(, 5) ' "B1:F1048576"
    
    Dim rrg As Range
    Dim rlCell As Range
    
    ' Start loop e.g. 'For RowOffset = 1 to whatever'
    
    Set rrg = crg.Rows(2 + RowOffset)
    Set rlCell = rrg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If Not rlCell Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range(rrg.Cells(1), rlCell).Interior.Color = vbBlack
        Set rlCell = Nothing ' don't forget to reset since in a loop
    End If
    
    ' End loop e.g. 'Next RowOffset'
```